# Heroku Nodejs can't start app at launch

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

This is the log files:

```
2018-03-20T11:45:03.569723+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1 
2018-03-20T11:45:03.569953+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-03-20T11:45:03.570261+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. 
2018-03-20T11:45:03.570109+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the webtech_team1@1.0.0 start script.
2018-03-20T11:45:03.575871+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-03-20T11:45:03.576049+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-03-20T11:45:03.576172+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! /app/.npm/_logs/2018-03-20T11_45_03_571Z-debug.log 
2018-03-20T11:45:03.636794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-20T11:45:05.175983+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=webtech-team1.herokuapp.com request_id=c0080960-f377-4e04-ab4f-89dc696b00ee fwd="193.191.150.3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-03-20T11:45:05.536530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=webtech-team1.herokuapp.com request_id=e46e00d3-3f8c-4ec1-84ea-9420b08e5e5d fwd="193.191.150.3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "webtech_team1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/CarolineVG/webtech_team1.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/CarolineVG/webtech_team1/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/CarolineVG/webtech_team1#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "pug": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

my index.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const pug = require('pug');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; //lets the port be set by Heroku

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.json() );
// link to css and img
app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/index') );

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

added route/index.js file

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();

/* home */
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('./home', {title: 'Home'}); 
});

/* kweeni */
router.get('/kweeni', function(req, res){
    res.render('./kweeni', {title: 'kweeni'}); 
});

/* wat is */
router.get('/watis', function(req, res){
    res.render('./watis', {title: 'watis'}); 
});

module.exports = router;
```

I already look at this document (https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit/issues/12 ) and changed following things:
- add start script in package.json
- add procfile 
- change port variable

I still get an application error, anyone an idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add your ./router/index file

Comment: can you show your router/index.js

Comment: I added it in the post

Comment: one more thing caroline can you post the logs of yesterday 2018-03-20 if possible because log may give an idea what's happening with an application while it is running. log path is /app/.npm/_logs/2018-03-20T11_45_03_571Z-debug.log

Comment: this is in the log file: /usr/bin/less: /usr/bin/less: cannot execute binary file

Comment: I asked you post here debug log of npm as I post the path of log file

Comment: I tested your code on a local machine so it works fine. so please provide log file to resolve an issue.

Comment: I added dependencies in the package.json file and now it works :o thanks for your help and patience! :)